# Flutter: Remove all SnackBars

Tags: flutter

In my app, it is possible (and intended!) that multiple `SnackBar` elements are created. These `SnackBar` elements are queued and displayed one after another which is all well and fine. However, if I go to a different screen and then go back (so `push` and `pop` a route) all `SnackBar` elements are still there.

So I would like to remove all `SnackBar`s upon pushing a route.

I tried counting my `SnackBar` elements and calling `scaffoldKey.currentState.removeCurrentSnackBar()` that many times in the following locations:

- before `Navigator.push()` which works, however, since I have multiple points where I push something I would like to use some callback.
- in `didPushRoute()` from `WidgetsBindingObserver`, however, even after registering the observer, this method is never called. (`ChangeAppLifecycleState()` is called so the registering seems to be not completely wrong?)
- in `dispose()`. This actually produces my intended behavior but throws exceptions from `AnimatedBuilder` (Exception text: "`setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`"), which I would like to avoid, even if the animation library seems to catch those.

If everything fails, I suppose I could just wrap `Navigator.push()` in a helper function that also clears the `SnackBar` queue but I hoped that there would be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, I ended up writing the following function and call it everywhere instead of Navigator.pushNamed()

```
Future<T> _pushNamedWrapper<T extends Object>(
    BuildContext context,
    String routeName, {
    Object arguments,
  }) {
    for (int snackbarsLeft = _snackbarCounter;
        snackbarsLeft > 0;
        snackbarsLeft = snackbarsLeft - 1) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.removeCurrentSnackBar();
    }

    return Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeName, arguments: arguments);
  }
```

here, `_snackbarCounter` is a counter var that will be incremented whenever a snack bar is created or decremented as soon as it disappears. Roughly like this:

```
// function where you want your snackbar to be triggered
() { 
  _snackbarCounter = _snackbarCounter + 1;
  Scaffold.of(context)
    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: // your content...
    ))
    .closed
    .then((SnackBarClosedReason reason) =>
      _snackbarCounter = _snackbarCounter - 1);     
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**You can use this to remove Snackbar in Flutetr2**

`ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();`

**Example code**

```
onPressed: () {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('New Snackbar'),
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: this is the new way

Answer (score 5):

To clear all `SnackBar`s, there is a `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars()` method which can be used in your `pushNamed` wrapper. :-)